# Como trocar field de exibição de um select usando CakePHP3

Tags: php, cakephp, view, cakephp-3

Sou novo no CakePHP e estou encontrando uma dificuldade para exibir os dados de forma correta.
`// src/Template/Bookmarks/add.ctp`
`echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options' => $users,'empty' => 'Selecione']);`
O trecho acima me exibe um select com o ID de usuário, que é minha chave estrangeira, porém, apesar de querer manter o valor (`value=""`) do campo como o ID, na exibição gostaria o e-mail do usuário. Existe alguma maneira simples de se alterar essa exibição?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro do arquivo Tables(no caso `BookmarksTables.php # src/Model/Table/BookmarksTables.php`), na função `initialize()` adicione o `setDisplayField()` no `$this->belongsTo();`.
no final das contas fica mais ou menos assim:

```
$this->belongsTo('Bookmarks', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
])->setDisplayField(
    '<column_name_user>'
);
```

resultado:

```
<select name="user_id" id="user-id">
    <option value="7">Felipe Sá</option>
</select>
```